# Plugin creation in nopCommerce

Tags: plugins, nopcommerce

I am new to NopCommerce. I need to develop my new plugin and not do buy or update.
So I have started with the provided helps given by nopcommerce plugin. Some problem I am facing and some understandings missing

1. I cant add view
2. My understanding about plugin is like usercontrol in asp.net You can add it in any page.
   Is that true?

I am trying to place my plugin (ProductAvailableAtlocation) on Product page where plugin accepts value and tell customer is the product available at his city or not?

1. How to plugged in Product page?

Answer (score 1):

**for the first part on how to add a view:**

    you can add it simply from visual studio you can add a file and after that you can edit its extension to cshtml in your plugin project.

**for the second part:**

    yes you can, add a widget plugin and plug it in anywhere in the page.

**for the third part on how to plug a plugin in the product page:**

    In the Nop.Web->Views->Catalog you can find a a view called (for example) ProductTemplate.Simple.cshtml

in this view if you searched for @Html.Widget ... you will find alot of view parts which you can plug your plugin view in... this is how nopCommerce is build .. it's build so that you as a developer can plug you plugins in each and every part in the page so you need to analyze the source to learn it's usage, it's pretty simple.

Comment: As per your suggestion I have added simple text file and change its extension to .cshtml and build the solution I got error Error   " 32 Assembly 'Nop.Web.Framework, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'"  then I changed the system.web.mvc version of Nop.Web project and make it to 4.0 then also same error occured

Comment: take a look at http://www.nopcommerce.com/docs/77/how-to-write-a-nopcommerce-plugin.aspx and also http://www.nopcommerce.com/docs/75/plugin-with-data-access.aspx to start building your plugin

Answer (score 0):

> 1. I cant add view.

You can copy any existing view in your plugin and update content as per your requirement.

> 2. My understanding about plugin is like usercontrol in asp.net You can add it in any page. Is that true?

No, that is not true. Plugin is external class library project where you can extend nopCommerce features and add new features via plugin without touch nopCommerce code.
You can integrate third party with nopCommerce via plugin like Erp, CRM, API etc.

> I am trying to place my plugin (ProductAvailableAtlocation) on Product page where plugin accepts value and tell customer is the product available at his city or not?
>
> How to plugged in Product page?

For this you need to create widget plugin and display check availability form/section on product detail page.
You can take reference from **Nivo Slider plugin** and you need to just update widget from Homepage Top to select any one from product detail page and write code as per your requirement in PublicInfo method(nopCommerce 3.90 or below version, for nopCommerce 4.00 - you've to write in ViewComponent ) and it'll work.